# What does the word "layout" mean in CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout

We see the word **layout** pretty much all the time. When we say **flex layout** or **normal flow layout**, what do we actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

Page layout is the arrangement of visual elements on a page.